# Box Plotting for multiple variables

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I have a dataset with 14 variables, all numerical but with very different scales. My first attempt at a boxplot was not very representative:

```
> boxplot(dd$crim, dd$zn, dd$indus, dd$chas, dd$nox, dd$rm, dd$age, dd$dis, dd$rad, dd$tax, dd$ptratio, dd$bb, dd$lstat, dd$medv)
```

[image: Boxplot]
So now I'm looking to create multiple individual box plots, side by side such that each plot has a suitable scale and is more readable and presentable. Is this possible?

Comment: Scale the values before plotting: `boxplot(scale(mtcars))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what is mtcards?

Comment: It is an example data that comes with R, replace it with your dataframe, something like: `boxplot(scale(dd[, c("crim", "zn", "indus", ...) ]))`